# Calculate if a geographical point is included in a rectangular area defined from one of it bisection

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spherical-coordinates

With a path of geographical point defined as follow: `lat,lng|lat,lng|lat,lng|etc`, I'd like to determine from which segment of the path a geographical location is nearby.

To do so, I'd like to define an area of proximity defined this way:

```
A-------B-------C-------D-------E
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       | Here  |       |
|       |       |       |       |
V-------W-------X-------Y-------Z
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
|       |       |       |       |
F-------G-------H-------I-------J
```

where:

- each segment of the path is defined this way: `[V(lat,lng),W(lat,lng)]`
- and for each segment, a rectangular area is defined such as the path is one bisection of the rectangle, and the perpendicular sides of that bisection have an arbitrarily defined length (e.g.: 100m on each side of the path).

How to calculate the geographical coordinates of A,B,C,D, etc, and then calculate if a location is included in the areas defined by these coordinates ?

Comment: This could be of help: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865375/orthogonal-lines-on-mercator-projection/1865664#1865664

Comment: If you want an answer, you should clarify your question (a lot). For instance, I don't understand what "one bisection of the rectangle" means. Are you trying to do this with a standard earth model such as WGS84? You do realize that intersections of pairs of lat/long lines are not rectangular.